# How to implement/use Artificial immune system(AIS) in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to machine machine learning algorithms and classification techniques.
I have created a dataset, and trained a model with a `SVM` in python using `sklearn` module.
But now I have to change my approach from `SVM` to `artificial immune system`. My question thus is, Is there a module for AIS  in python that I can use? Just like `Sklearn` which provides `SVM`.
If there is none, Where can I find an example or help on implementing one ?
Below is my code in `SVM`, in case anyone would need it.

```
# In the name of GOD
# SeyyedMahdi Hassanpour
# SeyyedMahdihp@gmail.com
# SeyyedMahdihp @ github

import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, model_selection
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('final_dataset123456.csv')
x = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
y = np.array(df['label'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.36, random_state=39)
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
ar = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.058824,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.25,0,0,0,0,0.020833,0.2,0.090909,0,0.032258,0,0,0,0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0.058333,0,0,0.1,0,0.125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
br = [0.5,1,1,0.254902,0.853933,1,1,0.254902,1,0.27451,0.2,1,0.4,0.176471,1,1,1,1,0.625,1,0.125,1,0.393939,0.857143,0.052632,1,0.75,0.847826,1,1,0.583333,0.7,1,1,1,0.729167,0.6,0.818182,1,0.193548,0.333333,1,0.674419,1,1,1,0.8,1,1,0.2,0.37037,1,0.8,0.529412,0.375,1,1,0.23913,1,1,1,1,0.666667,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0.23913,0.7,0.7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.23913,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.666667,1,0.7,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
example_measures = np.array([ar,br])
example_measures = example_measures.reshape(len(example_measures), -1)
prediction = clf.predict(example_measures)
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many artificial immune system applications implemented on WEKA Platform. You can download and use it from sourceforge.
Here is the link:
https://sourceforge.net/directory/?q=artificial+immune+system